# Remove or Change Color of a Pspicture Border

Tags: xetex, color, pstricks, border, pspicture

Consider the code (which compiles with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{red}%
\psframe[fillcolor=Beige,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,5)%
\psframe(-5,-5)(5,5)%

%top and bottom center
\rput[tl](-2.2,5){\psvectorian[width=4.3cm,flip]{71}}
\rput[bl](-2.2,-5){\psvectorian[width=4.3cm]{71}}

%four corners
\rput[tl](-5,5){\psvectorian[width=3cm]{63}}
\rput[tr](5,5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,mirror]{63}}
\rput[bl](-5,-5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,flip]{63}}
\rput[br](5,-5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,flip,mirror]{63}}

\rput(0,1.45){\scalefont{1.2}{\textbf{(i) How to remove black border?}}}
\rput(0,0.85){\scalefont{1.2}{\textbf{and (ii) How to change its color?}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces the picture

[image]

**Question:**

- (i) How may I remove the black border entirely?
- (ii) How may I change the color of the black border to, say, red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the border entirely, use the option `linestyle=none` for `\psframe`. The option `linecolor=red` will draw the border in red.

Note that you got `\psframe(-5,-5)(5,5)` twice in your code and you should remove the second one. Since `\psframe` has a black border and no fill by default, the second macro will still draw a black frame over the other frame.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{red}%
\psframe[linestyle=none,fillcolor=Beige,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,5)%      <-- change
% \psframe(-5,-5)(5,5)%                                                    <-- remove

%top and bottom center
\rput[tl](-2.2,5){\psvectorian[width=4.3cm,flip]{71}}
\rput[bl](-2.2,-5){\psvectorian[width=4.3cm]{71}}

%four corners
\rput[tl](-5,5){\psvectorian[width=3cm]{63}}
\rput[tr](5,5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,mirror]{63}}
\rput[bl](-5,-5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,flip]{63}}
\rput[br](5,-5){\psvectorian[width=3cm,flip,mirror]{63}}

\rput(0,1.45){\scalefont{1.2}{\textbf{(i) How to remove black border?}}}
\rput(0,0.85){\scalefont{1.2}{\textbf{and (ii) How to change its color?}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\psframe[linecolor=red](-5,-5)(5,5)%
```

you can also run the document with `lualatex`

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but when I run it as you suggest, I still get a black border. I also tried `\psframe[linecolor=red,fillcolor=Beige,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,5)%`  with the same result in Xelatex. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I also tried running it with lualatex, but it abends. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to replace my command with your existing one! `\psframe()()` draws a frame in black! With `[linecolor=red]` it is in red ...  or delete the second `\psframe` if you use the above one.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP request:

> (i) How may I remove the black border ***entirely***?

The option of `linestyle=none` is self-evident: it changes only the line style. To remove completely the borderline, do as with all the other lines within PSTricks<sup>1</sup>, that is, define the `linewidth` to a width of 0. The following code illustrates how you should change your code.

```
\psframe[linestyle=none, linewidth=0,fillcolor=Beige,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,5)%
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Denis Girou, *Complete PSTricks user guide*, https://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=doc/docs.